# Laravel how to check if Notification has been dispatched

Tags: laravel, notifications, jobs, job-scheduling

I initially have this email notification, which is triggered either on demand or on schedule. I want to know how to determine whether the notification has been dispatched (no errors found) or not (error reported in the `failed_jobs` table).

Invokable class to be triggered:

```php
<?php

class SendCertificates
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
                if($this->send_certificate($certificate)){
                    //NEVER EXECUTED, since return is VOID
                    $this->mark_as_delivered($certificate);
                }else{
                    //handle not sent, check error, etc.
                }

    }

    public function send_certificate(Certificate $certificate)
    {
        //'void' method 'notify' result used
        return Notification::route('mail',[
            $certificate->participant->email=>$certificate->participant->name,
        ])->notify(new CertificateIssued($certificate))
            ;
    }

}
```

For that last `return Notification` there's this warning:

> 'void' method 'notify' result used

So how do I determine the result of the Notification? To tell whether it was dispatched or not?

Comment: For development purposes you can use Telescope https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/telescope